# 404 Object Not Found for Javascript files

Tags: asp.net

I have a .Net 1.1 webapp.

I have a usercontrol (.ascx) that has links to 3 JS files in
script tags.

When I run the app and load a page with the usercontrol
all is fine and Firebug shows the js files listed.

But when I load another page that loads the usercontrol in a .aspx
in a new browser window Firebug reports 404 object not found
for the 3 JS files.

What could cause this??

Malcolm

Comment: Could you post the code that references the js from the ascx?

Comment: <script language="javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Secure/jquery-1.3.2.min.js") %>'></script>
<script language="javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Secure/jquery.copy.min.js") %>'></script>
<script language="javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Secure/jsTimesheetMonthly.js") %>'></script>

Comment: Is your website public so we can check it out?

Comment: I discovered the absolute paths were working and there was a bug in javascript as well causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the other page in a different location in the folder hierarchy. Perhaps reference you JS with a server side tag with a ~ in it.

So try changing your JS path to something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/someFolder/functions.js")%>'></script>
```

Use a tool like Microsoft Fiddler to help you understand the issue.

Comment: I have done that and it works fine in first page and firebug lists the files and you can see that src attribute is absolute path but, the page with the new window does not work, the js files are not listed in Firebug and no object not found message.????

Comment: Also with the second page the src attribute has the absolute path same as first page.

Answer (score 0):

You other .aspx page is in a different folder?  Possible at a different level in the folder hierarchy?  You need to adjust you JS file paths so that they are absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a basepath in you pages. In that case each url/image/css/js reference in your website will be relative to the basepath. Using a basepath in your site will prevent big issues when moving files into/from folders.

I usually place the base tag into the master page.

```
 <base href="<%=MyWebsite.Library.Configuration.BasePath%>" />
```

As you can see the basepath is requested from my configuration, but you can also use .NET code to dertermine the basepath.

Using this constructions saves me a lot of issues when developing my pages. Only problem is that Visual Studio does not completely known how to handle this which causes some warnings about incorrect CssClasses or links.